# How to have { on the 'new' line for object initialize in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How configure Visual Studio to format code like :

```cs
var obj = new Class1 {
    Property1 = 42,
    Property2 = "Some value",
    Property3 = new Class2 {
        Property1 = 7777,
        Property2 = "Other value"
    }
}
```

When Visual Studio auto format, it give :

```
var obj = new Class1
{
    Property1 = 42,
    Property2 = "Some value",
    Property3 = new Class2
    {
        Property1 = 7777,
        Property2 = "Other value"
    }
}
```

The curly bracket is put on a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the search tool (Control + Q). By typing "braces" you get the option "New line options for braces", where you can set it.

[image]

Comment: Like VS Code, amazing.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio C# code style, you need uncheck the option "Place open brace on new line for object..." :
[image]